# C/OSX/clang confusion: "symbol(s) not found" happening at link time instead of compile time

Tags: c, macos, opengl, gcc, clang

I have a question, but I'm not sure if it's about **C**, **clang** or **OSX**.

When I compile a simple **GLUT** program like so:

```
clang test.c -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
```

And I intentionally insert a function call that doesn't exist, like so:

```
thisFunctionIsNotDefinedAnywhere();
```

I get an error, as expected.  But here's the rub -- I don't get the error until link time!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "thisFunctionIsNotDefinedAnywhere" referenced from:
    _main in test-e099d2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Why is this?  Is this because **pre-C99** there were implicit declarations?  I've been programming for a long time and have never run into this before.  Is it because I've been spoiled on `GCC` and `MSVC` which (I seem to remember) cause a compiler error in this situation?  Or does it have to do with how framework linking works in **OSX**, which I am new to?

I appreciate any clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, this gives a warning with a recent version of clang. I tried it with the version that comes with Xcode 6.1, and got this compiler output:

```
$ clang test.c
test.c:2:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'thisFunctionIsNotDefinedAnywhere' is invalid in
      C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    thisFunctionIsNotDefinedAnywhere();
    ^
1 warning generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_thisFunctionIsNotDefinedAnywhere", referenced from:
      _main in test-376416.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Since using undeclared functions is legal in C, the compiler message can't be an error. But it does show a clear warning, without specifically enabling warnings with command line options.

Answer (score 0):

Because of implicit function declaration, if you enable warnings then you would be warned that `thisFunctionIsNotDefinedAnywhere();` is implicitly declared, returning `int` by default.

If you add a function prototype, then the warning will be gone, but then at the link stage, the compiler wont find the function definition, and issue the error.